# Difference b/w directory execute and file read permission

Tags: unix, file-permissions

What is the difference between execute permission of directory and read permission inside that directory?
As if both are set than can only we read the file.

Answer (score 6):

Read permission lets us read the directory, obtaining a list of all the filenames in the directory. Execute permission lets us pass through the directory when it is a component of a pathname that we are trying to access.

For Example
1) if you have a directory with only execute permission, you can use that directory in path resolution for accessing a file name, but you wont be able to list/read the files on the directory.
2) if you have a directory with only read permission, you can list/read the files on the directory, but you are not allowed to use that directory for your path resolution.

Answer (score 2):

1. **Read:** allows the affected user to list the files in the directory
2. **Execute:** allows the affected user to enter in to the directory. (that is, to make some directory your current working directory).
   Execute is needed on a directory to access the inode information of the files within.

The description can be confusing. I'm adding some examples to clarify this.

Say I have the following tree:

```
dir0
├── dir1
│   ├── dir2
│   │   └── test2.txt
│   └── test1.txt
└── testFile.txt
```

- From `dir0`, I execute `chmod 100 dir1/`.
  Now the user has only **`execute`** permission on`dir1`.

  1. Now I can enter `dir1` using `cd` command. But,
  2. `ls` will give me following error:
     `ls: cannot open directory '.': Permission denied`
     ***The user is able to enter the directory, But not able to list the contents inside***
- From `dir0`, I execute `chmod 400 dir1/`.
  Now user had only **`read`** permission on `dir1`.

  1. Now if I try `cd dir1`,
     I will get the following error:
     `bash: cd: dir1/: Permission denied`
  2. But, `ls dir1` will work, though it will show error message along with the result.
     `ls: cannot access 'dir1/test1.txt': Permission denied`
     `ls: cannot access 'dir1/dir2': Permission denied`
     `dir2  test1.txt`
     Note that it has listed the contents correctly in the last line.
     The errors occur because without execute permission, the user cannot pass through the directory.

Answer (score 1):

If the read permission is set, you can read (list) the directory. If the x permission is set, you can use a path that goes through the directory.